# An Issue in Custom Theme Generation

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I followed the steps in http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/theming
but get the following error when I want to build the app by `sencha app build` command.

(Note: that my OS is win 7 x64 and I installed the rubby with **rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p0-x64** installer and then installed Sencha Command by **SenchaCmd-3.1.1.274-windows.exe** installer. I also run the mentioned command through both regular command prompt window and "Start Command Prompt with Rubby" but the error was same. )

```
    [INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
    NoMethodError on line ["23"] of D: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/sass-3.1.7/lib/sass/engine.rb:293:in `_render'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/sass-3.1.7/lib/sass/engine.rb:240:in `render'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_required'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in run'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `each'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `block in run'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:45:in `perform'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/ge
    ms/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/bi
    n/compass:23:in `load'
      D:/Program Files/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/bi
    n/compass:23:in `<main>'
    [ERR]
    [ERR] BUILD FAILED
    [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code
     : 1
    [ERR]
    [ERR] Total time: 1 minute 20 seconds
    [ERR]
    [ERR] BUILD FAILED
    [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while e
    xecuting this line:
    [ERR] D:\temp\my-workspace\theme-demo-app\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:248: com.se
    ncha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1

[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 minute 21 seconds
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while e
xecuting this line:
D:\temp\my-workspace\theme-demo-app\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:248: com.sencha.e
xceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
```

After this I installed SASS by `gem install sass` command and it installed SASS 3.2.8 (although Sencha Command said that we don't need to install it when it installs SASS by himself :  [Introduction to Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#/guide/command) )...but the same error.

I Also installed compass through `gem install compass` (version :0.12.2 ) and execute the `Sencha app build` command again...and the same error received...

Any help?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
It seems that extjs is not compatible with ruby version 2.x  I read that some users experienced the same problem.

After de-installing ruby 2 and installing 1.9.3 it should work.

PS 
As I understand from the docs you don't need to install sass and compass because it's already part of sencha cmd